# How to convert RGB888 to Bayer GB/BG/GR formats?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to create a application that can convert BMP images into Raw Bayer(in all formats) image. I'd like to use this application to cross verify the actual output of my camera. So any help is appreciated. Please specify any link to any formulas for converting from RGB888 to Bayer formats. I'm using opencv in c++.

Edit: **For reducing the number of possible answers I'd like to consider only Bi-linear interpolated RGB888 image to its original Bayer image & also accepting the possible loss in this conversion.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image was interpolated with a 3x3, it is possible to get the color back from each pixel without any loss. Basically, just take the "blue" channel for the B pixel, the green channel for G pixels, and the red channel for R pixels. This will still work if the original was interpolated with higher-order interpolations but you'll have information loss. See http://www.vision-doctor.co.uk/area-scan-cameras/1ccd-colour-cameras/bayer-colour-interpolation.html.

Another way to think about it is that you are applying a "bayer filter" which eliminates the other colors for each pixel. This is true whether your capturing it via the camera or trying to remosaic the image.